# Evaluating DOM Manipulation Performance

Tags: jquery, dom, angularjs

I am trying to evaluate the performance of solely manipulating the HTML DOM between two frameworks. The two frameworks I'm trying to evaluate are JQuery and AngularJS. I was trying to write a test on http://jsperf.com/. However, I kept running into a JavaScript error related to the $scope object in AngularJS (yes, I was referencing the library).

I also know that you're not supposed to manipulate the DOM directly with AngularJS.

Either way, what is the best way to test the performance of adding 100 child elements to a DOM element using these two frameworks?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is a framework, while jQuery is just a JavaScript Library (which can also be used with Angular). Also, with Angular you're supposed to separate DOM manipulation with directives, quite different from not manipulating at all. As for adding 100 child elements to the DOM, how about `appendChild` (Angular also comes with jqLite, so you may use that as well).